# Load Google API's Dynamically

Tags: jquery, google-api

I'm trying to load Google's Api on click but it seems whenever I do so, the content gets hidden.

I firstly load the google's Api: `<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

Then on click I load an Api:

```
$(".test").click(function () {
        google.load("language", "1");
    });
```

...And the content gets hidden.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/hnr6v/

**So, how can I load Google's API's without the content to get hidden?** Is there any another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

natively, google.load loads on page load (not sure why it would remove all content). However, to dynamically load a library, you need to pass an object with a callback option to the third param of load:

```
google.load("language", "1", {"callback" : languageFileLoaded});

function languageFileLoaded()
{
    // do what you need here
}
```

http://code.google.com/apis/loader/#Dynamic

Comment: Hm... Like what would I add there? because there's nothing really to call after that...

Comment: Yeah, no need to call anything. As long as the callback exists, you're good.